# How to handle click event in my class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I am trying to add a class to a clicked element and remove it when user clicks other elements.

I have something like

```
<li ng-repeat='test in tests' >
    <a href='' ng-click='pickTest($index, $event)'>{{test.title}}</a>
</li>
```

js

```
 $scope.pickTest = function(index, event) {
     $(event.target).addClass('blur');
     //this works when user clicks one of the <a> tags 
     //but I want to remove the class if user clicks another <a> tag
  };
```

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` to determine if the class needs to be appended based on a certain condition. Additionally, using `$index` in an `ng-repeat` is really not advisable because it pose problems when filters are applied in the `ng-repeat` directive. You can create two functions, `isActive()` for the `ng-class` directive and `setActive()` to set the active item.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  
    var activeTest = {};
  
    $scope.tests = [{
      title: 'Test 1'
    }, {
      title: 'Test 2'
    }, {
      title: 'Test 3'
    }, {
      title: 'Test 4'
    }];
  
    $scope.setActive = function(test) {
      activeTest = test;
    };
  
    $scope.isActive = function(test) {
      return angular.equals(activeTest, test);
    };
  
     
  });
```

```css
.blur {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="test in tests">
      <a href="" ng-click="setActive(test)" ng-class="{blur: isActive(test)}">{{test.title}}</a>
    </li>      
  </ul>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ng-class, like this:

```
<li ng-repeat='test in tests' >
    <a ng-class={blur:blurActive} href='' ng-click='pickTest($index, $event);blurActive=true'>{{test.title}}</a>
</li>
```

Notice that you don't need to set `blurActive` to true inside your function, because `ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each "repeated item", so you can set it active inside the same `ng-click`, after you call your function, in this way the logic of your function won't be mixed with the design.

Answer (score 1):

Doing DOM manipulation in a controller is considered bad practice, you could achieve this angular way using `ng-class`:-

```
   <li ng-repeat="test in tests">
       <a href="#" ng-click="pickTest($index, $event)" 
            ng-class="{'blur': opt.selectedIdx == $index}">{{test.title}}</a>
   </li>
```

and in your controller, just do:-

```
$scope.opt = {}; //Set an initial value in your controller

$scope.pickTest = function(index, $event) { 
     $event.preventDefault(); //If you need
     $scope.opt.selectedIdx = index ; //Set the current index here, You could do this inline as well in the html, but probably better off having logic in your controller
}
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rXDUSV?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Just select all other elements with the class `blur` and remove the class from them before you assign the class to the currently clicked `element`.

```
$scope.pickTest = function(index, event) {
     $('.blur').removeClass('blur');
     $(event.target).addClass('blur');
};
```

Comment: I am afraid this is not an "angular-approach". Why reinvent the wheel and manipulate the DOM manually?..this is what angular basically frees you from doing.

Comment: Well,I've no experience using angular, mixing markup with logic is usually something i'm trying to avoid.